# Azure - Is it possible to set permission to read and write just only one user's data?

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory

I have registered application on MS Azure.
There is a user xxx@yyy.com.
All I want to do is read data about this user and change it.

My app does operations only on this single user. Is it possible to narrow down permissions to read and change only this user's data?

Comment: Is it acceptable that you write code to set the restriction about the target user? I mean that if you wanna change user data, you always need to use ms graph api, and those api have the permission to modify all users if the incoming request has enough api permission. So it seems no other choice to use graph api directly to achieve your goal, you need some other steps just like setting up a new api which is based on some graph api.

Comment: Yes, it is obvious that I can write a code to set that user. But I need to restrict permission on Azure, for security reasons. Possibility to modify all users is problematic in my case

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand your requirement correctly. In my opinion, after packaging the graph api, then you get a new api which can be used to modify a specific user. Next if you need this api opened to specific users, you can do these steps to achieve it. First, create an azure ad app used to [expose an api](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/quickstart-configure-app-expose-web-apis).

Comment: Then you create another azure ad app(app B) and set api permission exponsed just now, then make this app (app B) [restrict to specific users](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/howto-restrict-your-app-to-a-set-of-users).